# assign php variable if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, html, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="yes">
```

If the user checks this, the php variable `$vehicle_check` should hold the `value ="RA"` otherwise, the value will hold the default `"R"`.
Can I do this without javascript?

I tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitquotes'])){

    $check = $_POST['vehicle'];

    if ($check == 'yes'){
        $vehicle_check = 'RA';
    }
    else{
        $vehicle_check = 'R';
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you give some more light on *doesn't seem to work* ? What exactly you getting in `$check` ?

Comment: What is `submitquotes`? Show us the HTML.

Comment: Do you submit it to a php file ?

Answer (score 5):

The value of the checkbox is not useful - according to the html spec it'd be submitted only if checked, so check that instead. The following code should be enough:

```
if ( isset($_POST['vehicle']) ) {
    $vehicle_check = 'RA';
} else {
    $vehicle_check = 'R';
]
```

Comment: thanks! i am a newbie on php and thanks for the isset part. I thought this is only used when submitting forms. great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$vehicle_check = isset($_POST["vehicle"]) ? "RA" : "R";
```

Comment: I would have put this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`<input type="hidden" value="R"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="RA"/>`

If the user checks the checkbox then the value of checkbox overrides the value of hidden field, since they have the same name, but if the checkbox is not checked, then value of hidden field is taken. Remember if you are giving them `id` give them two different `id`